# Missing terminating ' character

Tags: c++, openxlsx

I'm trying to use a library called OPENXLSX in my QtCreator project. When I go to build I get 3 errors:

```
missing terminating ' character
expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before '\x303438'
expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘constexpr’
```

They complain of these 3 lines in the `XLDefinitions.h` file

```
constexpr uint32_t maxRows = 1'048'576;

constexpr uint16_t maxCols = 16'384;

constexpr uint8_t alphabetSize = 26;
```

Comment: Which C++ version are you using? Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Your compiler probably defaults to or is set to c++11 and `'` in numbers as digit separator have been added with c++14.

Comment: When I run `gcc -v` it says I have gcc version 9.2.0

Answer (score 0):

The code uses c++14 [digit separator](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#digit-separators) syntax and your compiler doesn’t seem to support it. Either remove the ticks from the numbers or rather get a compiler that supports newer c++ versions (or tell it to use a newer version if it needs that). There may be other things also that won’t work, or at least work better with newer compilers.

Comment: When I run `gcc -v it says I have gcc` version 9.2.0.

Comment: @GTA.sprx give it the option `-std=c++14` and it should handle it